# how to speed up garbage collection after deleting filestream data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

My question is on accelerating the speed of filestream garbage collector, the details are disuccsed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158702/sql-server-filestream-delete-speed)

Let me explain my scenario

1. For debugging/testing reasons i often need to copy a customer DB on my developement machine
2. Since DBs sometimes contain too much filestream blob data i prefer to delete it so the backup size moves from 10GB to 2 MB
3. I do `Update TABLE set BLOB = NULL`
4. And wait for hours or days

Since I just need to drastically and quickly remove blobs what else can work? Do i need to call `checkpoint` regularly or delete the Filestream files manually?

THanks.

**Update** 
Just to expresss myself better. This is what I do:

```
UPDATE TABLE_WITH_BLOBS SET BLOBFIELD = NULL
```

and then I ideally would like to have backup size to 2 MB...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "4. And wait for hours or days", are you waiting for the UPDATE to complete or waiting for garbage collection to take place?

CHECKPOINT can force the garbage collector to run as can using sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492195.aspx

Comment: Would it be possible to switch your database to simple recovery model (if it isn't already) and issue a checkpoint to see if that prompts garbage collection to run? 
Be aware that this will break the recovery chain if you are using FULL recovery model and if you switch back into this model then a new FULL backup will be needed.